# ¿Cómo insertar datos en base de datos SQLite en Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, base-de-datos, sqlite

Es una app de registro de usuarios (Nombre, Apellido) básicamente. Todo va bien. Lo que necesito es **Cómo puedo crear usuarios desde mi código en Android Studio.**.
(Cuando un usuario instala la aplicación, encuentra que no hay ningún usuario registrado, hasta que crea nuevos. Quiero crear usuarios que cuando alguien instale la app, los encuentra ya en la lista de usuarios registrados).
Tengo en mi   Helper:

```
public class DB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public DB(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, "Prueba", factory, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table datos(nombre text,apellido text)");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

}
public String guardar (String nombre, String apellido){
    String mensaje = "";
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contenedor = new ContentValues();
    contenedor.put("nombre", nombre);
    contenedor.put("apellido", apellido);

    try {
        database.insertOrThrow("datos",null, contenedor);
        mensaje = "Ingresado Correctamente";
    }catch (SQLException e){
        mensaje = "NO Ingresado";
    }

    return mensaje;
}
```

**Para leer los usuarios. En mi  DB Helper tengo:**

```
    public ArrayList llenar_lv(){

    ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String q = "SELECT * FROM datos";
    Cursor registros = database.rawQuery(q, null);

    if (registros.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            lista.add(registros.getString(0));
            //lista.add();
        }while (registros.moveToNext());

    }
    return lista;
}
```

**Y en la actividad donde se leen los usuarios registrados:**

```
public class Lista extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView lv;
ArrayList<String>lista ;
ArrayAdapter adaptador;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);

    DB db = new DB(getApplicationContext(), null, null, 1);
    lista = db.llenar_lv();
    adaptador = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lista);
    //adaptador = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, lista);

    lv.setAdapter(adaptador);


//Ordeno la lista
    Collections.sort(lista);
    for(String temp: lista){
        System.out.print(temp);
    }

//Cuando pulso un usuario

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            String valor = (String) adaptador.getItem(position);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Detalles.class);
            intent.putExtra("detalle", valor);
            startActivity(intent);

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pulsaste "+valor, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: Cual es tu problema exactamente? Lo que pude entender es que quieres que aplicacion tenga usuarios por defecto cuando se instale la app.

Comment: Exactamente!! Es eso lo que quiero! Crear usuarios por defecto.

Comment: en onCreate de la clase que extiende de SQLiteOpenHelper insertas los datos. Mira esta respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/158059/donde-inicializar-una-bd-sqlite-en-android/158113?noredirect=1#comment297339_158113

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear los usuarios por defecto cuando se crea la base de datos en el metodo `onCreate` de la clase DB. Solo necesitarias especificar el insert despues de crear la tabla:

```
public class DB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public DB(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, "Prueba", factory, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table datos(nombre text,apellido text)");

    // una vez creada la tabla, agregamos el usuario admin
    db.execSQL("insert into datos(nombre, apellido) values('admin','sys')");
}


 //...
```

Comment: Tras añadir el codigo para crear el usuario admin, se detiene la app cuando intento leer los usuarios de la base de datos.

Comment: Como lo lees que esa parte no está en tu pregunta

Comment: He editado la pregunta. Para leer los usuarios uso el codigo de los dos últimos apartados de mi pregunta. Me funciona bien cuando leo usuarios creados desde la actividad de registro de usuarios.