# ¿Donde inicializar una BD SQLite en Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, insert

He creado una tabla de una sola fila donde la única función será actualizar unos valores. Sólo tengo que hacer un INSERT con unos valores por defecto que se ejecute la primera vez

Hago lo siguiente pero sin éxito. ¿Donde puedo hacer este insert para que solo se ejecute la primera vez que instale y abra la app?

```
public class BD extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    String sqlCreate = "CREATE TABLE jugador (codigo INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                         "nombre TEXT DEFAULT 'Jugador')";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(sqlCreate);
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO jugador (nombre) VALUES ('jugador') ");

    }
}
```

Comment: Antonio, lo estas realizando correctamente, lo que sucede es que el metodo onCreate se llamo cuando instalaste por primera vez la aplicacion y la estructura posiblemente es incorrecta, te sugiero alguna de las 3 opciones en la respuesta que  agrego.

Answer (score 0):

Si vas agregar datos "definitivos", lo realizas en `onCreate` de la clase SQLiteOpenHelper.
Si son datos que primero necesitas obtener, por ejemplo de algún EditText (MainActivity), entonces debe
realizarse en esa clase.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(sqlCreate);
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(TuColumnaNombre, "jugador1");
        values.put(TuOtraColumna, "x");
        db.insert(TU_TABLA, null, values);
        // para agregar mas filas:
        values.clear();
        values.put(TuColumnaNombre, "jugador2");
        values.put(TuOtraColumna, "y");
        db.insert(TU_TABLA, null, values);
        }
    }
```

Para ver los cambios y que no muestre algún error elimina la app
del emulador/dispositivo e ir a File-`Invalidate Caches/restart`

Comment: Invalidate Caches/restart solo es usado para el cache de Android Studio no de una aplicación instalada.

Answer (score -1):

> ¿Donde puedo hacer este insert para que solo se ejecute la primera vez
>   que instale y abra la app?

Lo puedes realizar en el metodo `onCreate()`, puedes crear un metodo y llamarlo en este punto

```
   @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(sqlCreate);

         //Realiza insercion de datos, unicamente al iniciar.

    }
```

de hecho lo estas realizando pero probablemente la tabla ya existe y tiene una estructura incorrecta, te sugiero 3 opciones:

1)Borra el cachè de la aplicaciòn.

2)Elimina la aplicaciòn.

3) puedes cambiar la version que asignas a la version de la Base de datos cuando llamas al metodo :

```
public BD(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }
```

Comment: **CP Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.